# how can i changed button's text "choose location" in one activity by response of new activity as "location-india"?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, radio-button

I have two activities.in activityone there are a choose a location button,when iwill clicked that button then another activity (where numbers of locations are there)will be displayed.when i will clicked one of them,then that location name will be displayed my activityone location button.here is my code

**activityOne.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    tools:context="com.agnesys.partha.odishamedicalservice.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#69F0AE">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/choose_your_location"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/odishamedical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**ActivityOne.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        OnClickButtonListener();
    }

    public void OnClickButtonListener() {
        final Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ActivityTwo.class);
                 startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

ActivityTwo.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#69F0AE"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioLocations"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_India"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:onClick="selectLocations"
            android:text="India" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_unitedState"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="selectLocations"
            android:text="@string/radio_unitedstate" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_SouthAfrica"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:onClick="selectLocations"
            android:text="@string/radio_southAfrica" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_united Kingdom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="selectLocations"
            android:text="@string/radio_unitedKingdom" />

    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

ActivityTwo.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;    

public class ActivityTwo extends AppCompatActivity {    

    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.location_main);    
    }

    public void selectLocations(View view) {
        final int PICK_LOCATION_REQUEST = 1;
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.radio_India:
                if (checked) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityTwo.this, ActivityOne.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_LOCATION_REQUEST);
                    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
                    button.setText("location-India");

                }
                break;
         }
    }    

}
```

suppose i am selecting india.den it won't be respond to privious activityOne.it is showing output as "unfortunatly app has stopped".

[image]

Comment: use stratActivityforResult to call second activity and setResult after back from second activty to first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Activity 1,instead of calling startActivity() method,call startActivityForResult() to start second Activity.On second Activity,on click of an item call setResult with your data intent and finish the second Activity.

On First Activity,add onActivityResult to receive your intent data from seconds activity and update it on your button

Comment: thnaks for your helpful suggesion. @Ramprasad

Answer (score 0):

My Suspect is your button on which you are trying to set text after calling startActivity is not a part of xml for ActivityTwo.

```
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setText("location-India");
```

This R.id.button exist in activity_one.xml not in location_main.xml.

Answer (score 0):

in your Activity one:

```
public void OnClickButtonListener()
{
    final Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ActivityTwo.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent,101);

                }
            }
    );
}
```

and add onActivityResult method

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
// Check which request we're responding to
if (requestCode == 101) {
    // Make sure the request was successful
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // Get data from intent
String text = data.getStringExtra("button");
button.setText(text);
    }
 }
}
```

in your ActivityTwo

```
public void selectLocations(View view) {
    final int PICK_LOCATION_REQUEST = 1;
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio_India:
            if (checked) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("button","location-India");
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks .this logic is very helpful for me.but a little bit changes should be done on that.in ActivityTwo class after setResult(),finish() should be written,otherwish in ActivityOne class button couldnot be worked.